# Repeat-replace fields in single lines within text files

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to batch replace a delimited field in every line of many text files (actually *.dlf) in the following way:

xxx|xxx|a|xxx|DD|..

with

xxx|xxx|a|xxx|a|..., etc.

Is there a syntax in cygwin or other DOS shell that I can used to do this, or even an app which will serve?  Processing indirectly with Excel and Word is tiresome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gawk` to replace specific fields with new values:

```
sh-3.2$ echo "xxx|xxx|a|xxx|DD|.." | gawk -v FS="|" -v OFS="|" '{$5="a"; print}'
xxx|xxx|a|xxx|a|..
```

Comment: Thanks, so GAWK will replace the "DD" in field 5 with the "a" in field 3 for every line in every file using this syntax? This is a revision field and will change with most every line.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear that that was what you want.  Use `$5=$3` instead of `$5="a"`.  As far as how to use it, its a filter `cat oldfile.txt | filter >newfile.txt && mv newfile.txt oldfile.txt` will actually do a replace for one file.

Comment: yay; it works on single files so far. Can I batch it for a large numbers of subfolders with text files in each folder?